# How to Refresh or Flush the C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, c#-4.0

`This is my Entry Form of my Application.`

[image]

While Clicking the OK button, It will go to next form for further
 processing.My Second form is

[image]

In the second Form, I have to choose,any one option button and then press ok button.After pressing ok button,i just calling some function and then it will return to Form1.But Form1 has not getting its control for some seconds.It looks like getting collapsed and needs to be refreshed.but i don't know how to refresh a form? Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

It looks like,

[image]

Comment: can you post a code how and where you are calling second form?

Comment: do you have some long-time operations on the first form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call

```
this.Invalidate();
```

or

```
this.Refresh();
```

On the Form to update it.

Answer (score 4):

You can redraw the Form by:

```
Form1.Invalidate();
```

or

```
Form1.Refresh();
```

**EDIT:**
Some loops and operations on the same thread of `Form1` may cause it to stop responding. If it does, you may use the [`BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-7.0) class to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

> Calling the Invalidate method does not force a synchronous paint; to
>   force a synchronous paint, call the Update method after calling the
>   Invalidate method. When this method is called with no parameters, the
>   entire client area is added to the update region.

[Control.Invalidate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx)

And use BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Form.Invalidate();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invalidate.aspx) or [`Form.Refresh();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) methods.