# Use Form Constructor repeatedly to refresh the label text

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh

I'm **newbie** for C# and i have a little project. I'm stucked somewhere. I explained it here (with sample source codes) :

I have a form application. I'm asking users select an option from 2 buttons. There are 2 buttons (YES and NO) . My codes like this :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public int choice=0;
   public Form1()
   {
      if(choice == 0)
      {
         label.Text = "Please push one of these buttons :";
         // And there are buttons below this label
      }
      else if(choice == 1)
      {
         label.Text = "You just pushed YES button";
      }
      else if(choice == 2)
      {
         label.Text = "You just pushed NO button";
      }
   }

   private void buttonYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       choice = 1;
       /*
          I have to use one of these here for redraw whole form
          this.Refresh();
          this.Invalidate();
       */
   }
   private void buttonNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       choice = 2;
       /*
          I have to use one of these here for redraw whole form
          this.Refresh();
          this.Invalidate();
       */
   }
}
```

As you see, when user click one of YES or NO button, whole constructor function should be re-executed. And label should be "You just pushed YES / NO button".

But when i use this.Refresh() , nothing happening when i clik buttons. Still label is "Please push one of these buttons :" .

When i use this.Invalidate() , all buttons disappering, and label is still "Please push one of these buttons :" .

What should i do ?

Thanks.

**PS**
I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347714/how-to-refresh-or-flush-the-c-sharp-windows-form) BEFORE ask this one. But as you see, accepted answer not working for me.

Comment: You should put your if statements in a method and then call that method from within the methods you have set up for Yes/No.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invalidating or refreshing doesn't call the constructor again. The constructor is called exactly once when the form is created, and invalidating doesn't create a new form. Put the logic for changing stuff in another method and call that from the constructor AND from the event handlers - but do note for posterity that calling instance methods or accessing variables from the constructor isn't really the nicest way of doing this stuff - but for your purposes here it's the simple solution.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public int choice=0;
   public Form1()
   {
      UpdateForm();
   }
   private void UpdateForm(){
      if(choice == 0)
      {
         label.Text = "Please push one of these buttons :";
         // And there are buttons below this label
      }
      else if(choice == 1)
      {
         label.Text = "You just pushed YES button";
      }
      else if(choice == 2)
      {
         label.Text = "You just pushed NO button";
      }
   }
   private void buttonYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       choice = 1;
       /*
          I have to use one of these here for redraw whole form
          this.Refresh();
          this.Invalidate();
       */
       UpdateForm();
   }
   private void buttonNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       choice = 2;
       /*
          I have to use one of these here for redraw whole form
          this.Refresh();
          this.Invalidate();
       */
      UpdateForm();

   }
}
```

Comment: Really i need a little example (my over my example) for *Put the logic for changing stuff in another method and call that from the constructor AND from the event handlers*

Comment: Could you explain which part of my answer you didn't understand? Also, @jcolebrand kindly edited my answer to provide an example which should do exactly what you need.

Comment: with jcolebrand's update, now it's a great answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Eray:  This will make your code work but be sure to understand PhaDaFunk's "short version" because that's how your problem _should_ be solved.

Comment: Please check my comment on PhaDaFunk's answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best option if you want to keep the same variables as in the exemple. If you want a shorter version just change the label directly in the `Form1 Constructor`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public int choice=0;

   public Form1()
   {
       buttonYes.Click += (s,e) => { 
       choice = 1; 
       ChangeText(choice);};

       buttonNo.Click += (s,e) => {
       choice = 2;
       ChangeText(choice);};
   }


  private void ChangeText(int userChoice)
  { 
    if(choice == 0)
         label.Text = "Please push one of these buttons :";

      else if(choice == 1)
         label.Text = "You just pushed YES button";

      else if(choice == 2)
       label.Text = "You just pushed NO button";
  }

}
```

**Shorter Version**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    label.Text = "Push a button";
    buttonYes.Click += (s,e) => {label.Text = "Yes is pressed";};
    buttonNo.Click += (s,e) => {label.Text = "No is pressed";};
  }
}
```

Comment: This really is the better way to do things, if you need to handle them all in the same basic fashion.

Comment: Actually, it waas just a sample scenario. I'm developing a basic car computer . User's choice their destination city by clicking buttons. After that, there are some calculations etc. That calculations took about 50-60 lines. I mean it's not just label.Text = "..." . So this method not suitable for me. I have to repeat that 60 lines of code, if i follow this way

Answer (score 3):

This is how you really should be doing it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
       // Isn't there supposed to be InitializeComponent() here?

       // You should assign this in the designer, rather than here.
       label.Text = "Please push one of these buttons :";
   }

   private void buttonYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       label.Text = "You just pushed YES button";
   }
   private void buttonNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       label.Text = "You just pushed NO button";
   }
}
```

Since all the button is doing is changing a label, that should be done directly, not though changing a variable and refreshing.

**But why didn't it work my way?**

All Refresh and Invalidate do is redraw what is already on your form. They don't recreate it.

A constructor is designed to initialize an object once, when you create it. It cannot be called to 'reinitialize' or 'refresh' an object.

To avoid going into too much detail, I recommend you find an article/book on object oriented programming to learn more about constructors and other OOP idioms.

Comment: Ostensibly you would use a data element of some sort on the button itself and use one click handler, for what he's doing right now

Comment: Actually, it waas just a sample scenario. I'm developing a basic car computer . User's choice their destination city by clicking buttons. After that, there are some calculations etc. That calculations took about 50-60 lines. I mean it's not just `label.Text = "..."` . So this method not suitable for me. I have to repeat that 60 lines of code, if i follow this way.

Answer (score 0):

Main Constructor execute when new object created .

use an Method for do this . and i am shore this will work

```
       public string TextSwitcher(int choice)
       {
          Switch(choice) // choice is an int 
          {
// 1,2,3 is not an serial no they will pass by parameter  
             case(1):
              return "Please push one of these buttons :";
             brake;
             case(2):
              return = "You just pushed YES button";
             brake;
             case(3)
              return = "You just pushed NO button";
             brake;
          }
       }

   private void buttonYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       label.Text = TextSwitcher(2);
   }
   private void buttonNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       label.Text = TextSwitcher(3);
   }
```

i hop this will help you . and welcome for you'r thank's .

best of luck